# ASP.NET and Session Variables: I need real world opinions please

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory-management, session-variables

I am developing a light-weight online shop. This shop integrates with various sources. It absically serves as a "plugin" for different scenarios. I.e. Plugin for an accounting package to sell local stock on the web, and reflect sales back, etc.

My dilemma is this: I am battling to make a set decision on how to best implement the state information. This shop is template based, so I am loading all the template details from the DB on initial landing. I then store these details in session variable, and use it to set styles on elements as and when needed when the shop is doing its thing.

I am worried about load... I am easily reaching 100MB in in worker process. It seems to hover just under 100MB. But I am worried about scalability. I will need this shop to handle hundreds of concurrent users.

The shop itself does nto do any database requests. Everything is consumed from a web service/service (WCF) and put into session variables. And session variables only get loaded/re-loaded from the Web Reference if they are empty.

My current host caps me on 100MB. Which forces my worker process to be recycled, causing a view macstate filed error and resetting my session. I have benched on my local IIS and cant get it to really grow more than 100MB no matter what I do. It seems to jump to about 80MB and then settle there as memory gets recycled etc.

I am definately manually recycling all my WCF conenctions and variables as they are done srving their purpose. SO no memory leaks that I can find. As I said, it does not really grow, only uses x amount of memory, and then really hovers there.. slightly up or down...

Should I considder storing my session in a DB rather than memory?

Or should I change my approach completely? What would be you rela worl opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the template being loaded on a per-user level?  If not, then Application State seems more appropriate for it.  If it is, then yeah Session State is probably the way to go.

I would opt for an out-of-process, database-based Session State management solution, because your session state will also contain things like shopping cart contents and stuff.  You don't want people to lose everything in their session just because your server craps out at some point.  You want to make sure that every transaction (pending or finalized) and every item in the shopping cart is saved and available for retrieval after your web server crashes and is restored.

Comment: My concerns with storing session state in a DB, is I am doing DB reads and writes.. after I spent a considerable amount of effort to not rely on DB conenctions in my presentation... How will this effect performance? BUt I can definately concur about your views on absolutely persisting session info for cart etc...

Comment: Thanks Kon, going to use the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you must store this much in session state, and you're limited on process memory, then it seems like the database would be the way to go.  Just make sure that everything you are putting in `Session` is serializable, since that will be required.  More details are on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).  The database option is, of course, `SessionStateMode.SQLServer`.

Answer (score 0):

If the templates are the same for every user, you could also store them in [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) variables, (the same as session except one variable for all users).

If you suspect some variables to consume a lot of memory, but are sparsely use, you could also think about the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx). The system will remove the objects that are not used automatically, but you need to implement some code to "smart" load the from the database.

Comment: Hi GvS. Applications state won;t do it, I am running different shops on one domain, each shop ahs the sme source, but loads different template data. I am contemplating to look at cache or cookies, should bring my overhead down? My problem with cookies is that I am limited in teh amount of cookies. I am using quite alot of variables...

Comment: You could store the ID of the template in the session, and store the template itself in Application/Cache, using the ID as part of the key. Then you store only one copy of each template.

Comment: I am nto really farmiliar with cache, but it looks good... I am not getting clear information tho, of where it is stored? Is it stored on the client side, or if server side, global to teh app or current session?

Comment: The `Cache` as used in server-side code, is on the server. It's almost like Session or Application, excepts it throws out data after a while (when memory is needed, after a fixed interval, ...).

Comment: The Cache uses application scope.

Comment: Cache is more closely related to an Application variable rather than a Session variable.  If you stored per-user based items in Cache or Application, you will need to come up with a way of differentiating each users data.  Like one poster above said, you can append the user id somewhere in the variable name.  Another alternative is that you can set Session to store on the file system rather than in memory.  If you set session mode to StateServer, it uses the disk instead of the memory.

Comment: Sorry guys, was working my behind off pushing deadlines. Thanks for all the help. In my givin sceanrio, it seems to use DB for sessions is going to be the only real way to go.